# what is the function of class Queue in queue.py ?

Tags: python

I use windows 7 and python 2.7.

In a code containing Qt thread, the program receive cmd from the serial port and put it in the queue like this : `queue.Queue().put(cmd)`

what is the aim of this?
Here is the queue.Queue()

```
class Queue:
"""Create a queue object with a given maximum size.

If maxsize is <= 0, the queue size is infinite.
"""
def __init__(self, maxsize=0):
    self.maxsize = maxsize
    self._init(maxsize)
    # mutex must be held whenever the queue is mutating.  All methods
    # that acquire mutex must release it before returning.  mutex
    # is shared between the three conditions, so acquiring and
    # releasing the conditions also acquires and releases mutex.
    self.mutex = _threading.Lock()
    # Notify not_empty whenever an item is added to the queue; a
    # thread waiting to get is notified then.
    self.not_empty = _threading.Condition(self.mutex)
    # Notify not_full whenever an item is removed from the queue;
    # a thread waiting to put is notified then.
    self.not_full = _threading.Condition(self.mutex)
    # Notify all_tasks_done whenever the number of unfinished tasks
    # drops to zero; thread waiting to join() is notified to resume
    self.all_tasks_done = _threading.Condition(self.mutex)
    self.unfinished_tasks = 0

def task_done(self):
    """Indicate that a formerly enqueued task is complete.

    Used by Queue consumer threads.  For each get() used to fetch a task,
    a subsequent call to task_done() tells the queue that the processing
    on the task is complete.

    If a join() is currently blocking, it will resume when all items
    have been processed (meaning that a task_done() call was received
    for every item that had been put() into the queue).

    Raises a ValueError if called more times than there were items
    placed in the queue.
    """
    self.all_tasks_done.acquire()
    try:
        unfinished = self.unfinished_tasks - 1
        if unfinished <= 0:
            if unfinished < 0:
                raise ValueError('task_done() called too many times')
            self.all_tasks_done.notify_all()
        self.unfinished_tasks = unfinished
    finally:
        self.all_tasks_done.release()

def join(self):
    """Blocks until all items in the Queue have been gotten and processed.

    The count of unfinished tasks goes up whenever an item is added to the
    queue. The count goes down whenever a consumer thread calls task_done()
    to indicate the item was retrieved and all work on it is complete.

    When the count of unfinished tasks drops to zero, join() unblocks.
    """
    self.all_tasks_done.acquire()
    try:
        while self.unfinished_tasks:
            self.all_tasks_done.wait()
    finally:
        self.all_tasks_done.release()

def qsize(self):
    """Return the approximate size of the queue (not reliable!)."""
    self.mutex.acquire()
    n = self._qsize()
    self.mutex.release()
    return n

def empty(self):
    """Return True if the queue is empty, False otherwise (not 
reliable!)."""
    self.mutex.acquire()
    n = not self._qsize()
    self.mutex.release()
    return n

def full(self):
    """Return True if the queue is full, False otherwise (not reliable!)."""
    self.mutex.acquire()
    n = 0 < self.maxsize == self._qsize()
    self.mutex.release()
    return n

def put(self, item, block=True, timeout=None):
    """Put an item into the queue.

    If optional args 'block' is true and 'timeout' is None (the default),
    block if necessary until a free slot is available. If 'timeout' is
    a non-negative number, it blocks at most 'timeout' seconds and raises
    the Full exception if no free slot was available within that time.
    Otherwise ('block' is false), put an item on the queue if a free slot
    is immediately available, else raise the Full exception ('timeout'
    is ignored in that case).
    """
    self.not_full.acquire()
    try:
        if self.maxsize > 0:
            if not block:
                if self._qsize() == self.maxsize:
                    raise Full
            elif timeout is None:
                while self._qsize() == self.maxsize:
                    self.not_full.wait()
            elif timeout < 0:
                raise ValueError("'timeout' must be a non-negative number")
            else:
                endtime = _time() + timeout
                while self._qsize() == self.maxsize:
                    remaining = endtime - _time()
                    if remaining <= 0.0:
                        raise Full
                    self.not_full.wait(remaining)
        self._put(item)
        self.unfinished_tasks += 1
        self.not_empty.notify()
    finally:
        self.not_full.release()

def put_nowait(self, item):
    """Put an item into the queue without blocking.

    Only enqueue the item if a free slot is immediately available.
    Otherwise raise the Full exception.
    """
    return self.put(item, False)

def get(self, block=True, timeout=None):
    """Remove and return an item from the queue.

    If optional args 'block' is true and 'timeout' is None (the default),
    block if necessary until an item is available. If 'timeout' is
    a non-negative number, it blocks at most 'timeout' seconds and raises
    the Empty exception if no item was available within that time.
    Otherwise ('block' is false), return an item if one is immediately
    available, else raise the Empty exception ('timeout' is ignored
    in that case).
    """
    self.not_empty.acquire()
    try:
        if not block:
            if not self._qsize():
                raise Empty
        elif timeout is None:
            while not self._qsize():
                self.not_empty.wait()
        elif timeout < 0:
            raise ValueError("'timeout' must be a non-negative number")
        else:
            endtime = _time() + timeout
            while not self._qsize():
                remaining = endtime - _time()
                if remaining <= 0.0:
                    raise Empty
                self.not_empty.wait(remaining)
        item = self._get()
        self.not_full.notify()
        return item
    finally:
        self.not_empty.release()

def get_nowait(self):
    """Remove and return an item from the queue without blocking.

    Only get an item if one is immediately available. Otherwise
    raise the Empty exception.
    """
    return self.get(False)

# Override these methods to implement other queue organizations
# (e.g. stack or priority queue).
# These will only be called with appropriate locks held

# Initialize the queue representation
def _init(self, maxsize):
    self.queue = deque()

def _qsize(self, len=len):
    return len(self.queue)

# Put a new item in the queue
def _put(self, item):
    self.queue.append(item)

# Get an item from the queue
def _get(self):
    return self.queue.popleft()


class PriorityQueue(Queue):
'''Variant of Queue that retrieves open entries in priority order (lowest 
first).

Entries are typically tuples of the form:  (priority number, data).
'''

def _init(self, maxsize):
    self.queue = []

def _qsize(self, len=len):
    return len(self.queue)

def _put(self, item, heappush=heapq.heappush):
    heappush(self.queue, item)

def _get(self, heappop=heapq.heappop):
    return heappop(self.queue)
```

I do not know why in the program, a thread parsing the uart  be created and the command from the uart received be put in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

It is a constructor which create the FIFO Queue. In your case, you are creating a queue and putting `cmd` on queue. Here is the some useful [link](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/queue.html#queue.Queue).

> a thread parsing the uart be created and the command from the uart received be put in the queue.

So it does put something on the queue. The question is what do you want to achieve from this program?